# How to generate a .db file from TSMC 65nm Standard Cell Library？

Tags: verilog, hardware-acceleration, synthesis, hardware, asic

I have been using TSMC 180nm Standard Cell Library before and here is its directory structure：

[image]

In the directory of synopsys, things are as followers:

[image]

The file slow.db is used to synthesize the RTL Verilog in Design Compiler.

Now,I got a TSMC 65nm Standard Cell Library with similar directory structure to TSMC 180nm Standard Cell Library:

[image]

But in the directory synopsys,there is no db files but just a README file:

**This package contains no timing models. The timing models for this library are in separate *.tgz files whose name starts with "ft" and has an identical process, library and release name as the name of this tgz file.**

My question is how could i get the db file like "slow.db" in TSMC 180nm Standard Cell Library?

Thanks！

Answer (score 1):

You have to find the *.tgz file (Which is a Gnu-Tarred-Compressed file) and unpack it.

Note that TSMC, UMC, SMIC and the like are ***very*** protective about their IP and often provide *"get acquaintanced packages"* which lets you play with their libraries, but not do in-depth design. As such they may not have provided you with all the design sources required.

Especially the physical cell library will only be released after you transfer a significant amount of money.